# Mongo query inside a for-loop nodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to make a query that will look for a specific element in an array and print out the object that the specific element resides within. I wanna do this for every element in my dataset

Here's an example of what my dataset looks like (but with around 10k more datasets. These are just the first 2 sets in the database):

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6b19cb1be7e54a24344bd5"),
    "id" : 18009,
    "ingredients" : [ 
        "baking powder", 
        "eggs", 
        "all-purpose flour", 
        "raisins", 
        "milk", 
        "white sugar"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6b19cb1be7e54a24344bd6"),
    "id" : 28583,
    "ingredients" : [ 
        "sugar", 
        "egg yolks", 
        "corn starch", 
        "cream of tartar", 
        "bananas", 
        "vanilla wafers", 
        "milk", 
        "vanilla extract", 
        "toasted pecans", 
        "egg whites", 
        "light rum"
    ]
}
```

So what I want is, first of all to find the recipes where baking powder exsists, then I wanna print ot those objects where it exists. I wanna do the same for all of the ingredients. I have tried doing following to achieve this:

```
const path = "mongodb://localhost:27017/NN_Recipes";


mongo.connect(path, function(err,db) {

    console.log("Connected!")


    var allIngredients;


    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.collection('recipes_final').distinct("ingredients", function(err, resu) {

            allIngredients = resu;
            resolve();
        })
    }).then(data => {
        for(i = 0; i < allIngredients.length; i++) {

            var currentIngredient = allIngredients[i];

            var individualMatrix = db.collection('recipes_final').find({
                ingredients: currentIngredient
            }).toArray(function(error, response) {
                  // console.log(currentIngredient); //This will only print the very last element in the allIngredients[i], none of the other ones.

            });

            //all below is just things i tried to play around with.
        //     console.log(i)
        //     console.log(individualMatrix)
        //    console.log(allIngredients[i])
        }
       // console.log(allIngredients)
    })


});
```

anyone who can explain why it's only printing out the last element in my dataset?

Comment: you have missed `closure` inside for loop. like this (function(i) {  console.log(i);  })(0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to `async/await` everything, so every call will be made in order, one after the other :

```
mongo.connect( path, async (err, db) => {

    const recipes = db.collection('recipes_final'),
           allIngredients = await recipes.distinct("ingredients");

    for (let ingredients of allIngredients) {
        let individualMatrix = await recipes.find({ ingredients }).toArray()
        console.log(individualMatrix)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my question! Not very used to asyncronous programming, gotta read up on it more. Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome. Async programming requires some time and practice to get used to. I have optimized my code, cached the collection object, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use for loop, it isn't waiting for print output. Your for loop is not asynchronous, use [`async`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) for loop.

```
async.each(openFiles, saveFile, function(err){
    // if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the what is an issue with it, you have missed the `closure` inside the for loop

```
for(i = 0; i < allIngredients.length; i++) {
   (function(i){
        var currentIngredient = allIngredients[i];

        var individualMatrix = db.collection('recipes_final').find({
            ingredients: currentIngredient
        }).toArray(function(error, response) {
              // console.log(currentIngredient); //This will only print the very last element in the allIngredients[i], none of the other ones.

        });
       })(i)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use ES6 **let** or **closures**.

Database queries in your case is asynchronous. When you are executing a query like:

```
db.collection('collectionName').find().toArray(callback);
```

The `callback` function here is executed at next tick i.e. after the completion of your whole script. So, when the current tick is finished, `i` (of your for loop) has become equal to `allIngredients.length` and that is pointing to the last element. You can mitigate this by using a **closure** or `let` (if you are using ES6) instead of `var` to declare your `currentIngredient` variable as shown below:

```
for (i = 0; i < allIngredients.length; i++) {
  let currentIngredient = allIngredients[i];
  // rest of your code
}
```